# Magento2 static content deploy issue - RuntimeError: No matching definition was found

Tags: magento2, vagrant

Unable to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` without compilation error after upgrading Magento to 2.3.3 from 2.2.8.

Other messages included:

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2449/2533           ===========================> 96%    1 sec
Compilation from source: /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
variable @theme__color__primary-alt is undefined in file /var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Braintree/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 13, column 26

RuntimeError: No matching definition was found for `.lib-font-face in _typography.less

Answer (score 4):

Because my environment was running in Vagrant I had to re-sync back certain folder to the host, but did not include the /lib folder. This error has nothing to do with your theme less.

After copying over the /lib folder from 2.3.3 source to my project and running the following commands:

```
rm -rf lib/internal/Magento    
rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
```

Then running

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Completed succesfully.

Another way to debug less errors or see the exact issue in more detail is by running.

```
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --theme=Magento/blank --locale=en_US

node_modules/.bin/lessc -l var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.less
```

This will only show the blank theme errors.

Comment: For me the lib folder wasn't transferred over when upgrading Magento - after I've done this, setup:static-content:deploy worked fine, and the website started working properly again.